# RegEx to match a "\" before and after whitespace inside a word, then delete all other text in that line except the word containing the "\"

Tags: regex

I am using Notepad++ regex. I am trying manipulate a text file, to delete all text on all lines, except the actual IP and Subnet on each line, an example set of the file data would be:

```
    Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *> 42.106.152.0/24  158.209.255.8                          0 5747 23686 i
 *> 42.106.153.0/24  158.209.255.8                          0 5747 23686 i
 *> 42.239.69.0/24   158.209.255.8                          0 5747 23686 i
 *> 47.209.192.0/24  158.209.255.8                          0 5747 40844 18620 i
 *> 47.209.198.0/24  158.209.255.8                          0 5747 17105 18620 i
```

I would like a regex expression that would return only the IP and Subnet and delete the other text left and right. The text I want saved always includes a "/" and everything else must be discarded.

Requested output for the above example set should be:

```
42.106.152.0/24
42.106.153.0/24
42.239.69.0/24
47.209.192.0/24
47.209.198.0/24
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d{1,3}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\b([\d.]+/\d+).*
```

is your pattern,

```
\1
```

is your replacement.  Make sure you have "Regular Expression" checked in the search/replace dialogue.

Comment: This is close, however the output doesn't include the full IP address for example the output is only: 0/24
0/24
0/24
0/24
0/24. The first 3 octets of the IP are not included with that regular expression,please can you assist with that

Comment: You could be a bit more specific: `^.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d+).*$`.

Comment: @heptadecagram - With the \b added I am still getting the output of just 0/24 0/24 0/24 0/24 0/24 when using that regex. Thanks for the help so far, unfortunately there is something still not right with this one: .*\b([\d.]+/\d+).* as it only returns 0/24 0/24 0/24 etc on the example set

Comment: @tenub Thank you for that regex, only saw it now - it works nicely. heptadecagram thank you I just needed to be more specific like tenub pointed out. Problem is solved with the more specific one.

Comment: @tenub or more short `^.*?((\d{1,3}\.?){4}\/\d+).*$`

Comment: @MikeLezowski Or you can be non-specific at all: `.*?(\S*/\S*).*`

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, `1111/24`.

Comment: @tenub, agree, and i can provide billions of bad examples but why bothering when you already have pattern of expected data-input.

Comment: @tenub, 999.999.999.999/999 passes your pattern but that will never happen, right?